# Tick checkbox for timestamp in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, checkbox, timestamp, google-sheets-formula, google-forms

I'm creating a request/problem form in google form and responses are viewable and editable in google sheet. In the google sheet, I would like to have a timestamp checkbox for myself to whenever I'm done with the problem.

[It is look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3gUw.jpg)

...

Also, This is the function I put in column K(the timestamp) and the column J is the checkbox column.

=ArrayFormula(IF(ROW(K:K)=1,"DATE",IF(ISBLANK(K:K),"DATE",IF(J:J = true,IF(K:K<>"",K:K,NOW()),""))))

[The column K function in sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laL5y.jpg)

The function for column K work as intended and I just need to manually add the checkbox in column J which is fine enough.

But, the problem is happen when a new form is submitted and update the google sheet. Error message appear " "array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in K81."

[The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lgJd.jpg)

My objective as I mention above is to have a timestamp checkbox for each problem submitted by google form. Is there are any way to work around this?

Answer (score 1):

This error comes up when a function returns an array that is too big to display because something's in its way.

It could be that K81 has a whitespace character in it. Select the whole column under K1 and press <kbd>Delete</kbd>. It should remove any content that's not as obvious that it's there.